# invalid operands to binary expression ('NSString *' and 'NSString *')

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, string, int

I have the following code:

```
NSString  *String=TextField1.text + TextField2.text
```

its giving the error: `-invalid operands to binary expression ('NSString *' and 'NSString *')`

Comment: In objective-c '+' operator does not concatenate strings. use one of NSString's factory methods.

Comment: Also, by convention, variable names in Objective-C usually start with a lowercase letter. (for example `textField1` and `textField2`).

Answer (score 14):

You cannot do it this way, because Objective-C doesn't use '+' operator for concatenation.

This way should work:

```
NSString *concat = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@%@", TextField1.text, TextField2.text];
```

or

```
NSString *concat = [TextField1.text stringByAppendingString:TextField2.text];
```

Hope this works for you ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should use following

```
NSString *concat = [TextField1.text stringByAppendingString:TextField2.text];
```